# GPG: how to encrypt using a keyfile? (symmetric)

Tags: encryption, passwords, gnupg, key, gpg4win

In Ubuntu this produces a "filename.txt.gpg" file and works:

```
$ gpg --symmetric --passphrase-file keyfile.key filename.txt
```

In debian, I get a popup requesting I enter a password...

**How do I encrypt a file with a keyfile in debian?**

gpg version in debian:

```
$ gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.10
libgcrypt 1.8.3
```

Comment: The manpage says `--passphrase-file file ... Note that this is only used if the option  --batch has also  been given. This is different from GnuPG version 1.x.`